# How to code a data validation loop that consist of two numbers?

Tags: python

Here is my code here I've already coded the validation loop but I'm supposed to code a data validation loop to ensure that the number of days must be between 2 and 40 (Both 2 and 40 are valid) It works so that any number less than two is invalid and prints the message but numbers above 40 it does not print the error message.

```
dayPennies = 1

num_days = 0

total = 0.0


num_days = int(input('Enter the number of days: '))

while num_days < 2 and num_days > 40: 

num_days = int(input("Your entered number of days is invalid"))  

print ('Day  \t Pennies Earned for day')
print ('_______________________________')

for day in range (1, num_days + 1):
  print(day, '\t$', float(dayPennies / 100))
  total += dayPennies
  dayPennies *=2


print('The total salary for', num_days, \
      'days is: $', float(total/100))
```

Comment: Take a look at your while loop condition. Why would it only be true if `num_days` is less than 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you've entered the wrong condition in your while loop, it should be

```
while num_days < 2 and num_days > 40:
#rest of your code
```

EDIT
I know you said it worked but this is just a word of advice. When doing a project like this, it's best to put your calculations in a function and call your input outside of that function until you get the correct answer... then from there you put the correct answer as a parameter in that function. Here's what I mean.

```
from tkinter.tix import Tree

num_days = 0

def calculatePennies(num_days):
    dayPennies = 1
    total = 0.0

    print ('Day  \t Pennies Earned for day')
    print ('_______________________________')

    for day in range (1, num_days + 1):
        print(day, '\t$', float(dayPennies / 100))
        total += dayPennies
        dayPennies *=2


    print('The total salary for', num_days, \
        'days is: $', float(total/100))


num_days = int(input('Enter the number of days: '))

while num_days < 2 or num_days > 40:
    num_days = int(input("Your entered number of days is invalid"))

calculatePennies(num_days)
```

As you can see I put calculatePennies as a function, it's cleaner and more readable while being easier to go back and change. Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you I've changed it but now the error message won't even display for either numbers that are less than 2 or greater than 40.

Comment: @Jasiah Maybe your error message should not be in the loop?

Comment: The problem is your use of and in the while loop. It should be or because with and, you're saying the number has to be less than 2 AND greater than 40 which is impossible (a number cant be equal to two numbers).

Comment: Yeah, it worked finally appreciate it! Before when using validation loops I would create two but I only needed to create one for validation and just keep them together.

Comment: just updated my answer to help you better. Hope this helps! Have a good day. Also excuse my use of camal case lol its your preference.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fixed and more Pythonic way to write your code:

```py
ps = 1
total = 0
valid_days_range = range(2, 41)

days = int(input('Enter the number of days: '))

while days not in valid_days_range:
    print('Your entered number of days is invalid!')
    days = int(input('Enter the number of days: '))

print('Day\t$ Pennies Earned for day')
print('---\t------------------------')

for day in range(days):
    print(f'{day + 1}\t$ {ps / 100:0,.2f}')
    total += ps
    ps *= 2

print(f'The total salary for {days} days is: $ {total / 100:0,.2f}')
```

For `days = 19`, it will yield the following output:

```
Enter the number of days: 19
Day $ Pennies Earned for day
--- ------------------------
1   $ 0.01
2   $ 0.02
3   $ 0.04
4   $ 0.08
5   $ 0.16
6   $ 0.32
7   $ 0.64
8   $ 1.28
9   $ 2.56
10  $ 5.12
11  $ 10.24
12  $ 20.48
13  $ 40.96
14  $ 81.92
15  $ 163.84
16  $ 327.68
17  $ 655.36
18  $ 1,310.72
19  $ 2,621.44
The total salary for 19 days is: $ 5,242.87
```

Another option is to use an *inequality* instead:

```py
ps = 1
total = 0

days = int(input('Enter the number of days: '))

while not (2 <= days <= 40):
    print('Your entered number of days is invalid!')
    days = int(input('Enter the number of days: '))

print('Day\t$ Pennies Earned for day')
print('---\t------------------------')

for day in range(days):
    print(f'{day + 1}\t$ {ps / 100:0,.2f}')
    total += ps
    ps *= 2

print(f'The total salary for {days} days is: $ {total / 100:0,.2f}')
```